tinymce code plugin allows edits to uneditable tags
I have the below settings for my tinymce editor.
editable_class: 'tiny-editable',
editable_root: false,

In the editor, this only allows edits to html tags with class="tiny-editable".
In the code plugin window, any part of the html can be edited.
Is there a way restrict the code plugin to only allow editing to tags that have the class listed in the editable_class property?
If not, is there some other way of accomplishing this?
Looking at the code plugin documentation, I don't see a way of doing this, but maybe I'm missing something.
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/latest/code/
Thanks!
